# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to do a put request using axios to update a given Recipe by the authenticated user in the database basic rest API. But i am having an error in my code saying the 'then' is undefined.

```
`
 // My updateRecipe.jsx Action file

  import axios from 'axios';
  export const RECIPE_UPDATED = "RECIPE_UPDATED"

  const recipeUpdated = (recipe) => {
  //console.log(recipe)
     return {
       type: RECIPE_UPDATED,
       recipe
           }
      }

   const updateRecipe = (data) => {
      return dispatch => {
         // console.log(data)
         // console.log(dataid)
         axios.put(`http://localhost:8009/api/v1/recipes/${data.id}`, data)
         .then(() => dispatch(
             //console.log(data),
             recipeUpdated(data)
    )).catch( error => {
        //console.log(error.message)
        error} )




   }
 }

 export  {
    updateRecipe,
    recipeUpdated,
}`
```

This is my Reducer file:

```
import { SET_RECIPES } from '../action/recipeAction.jsx';
import { RECIPE_FETCH } from '../action/RecipeFetch.jsx'
import { RECIPE_UPDATED } from '../action/updateRecipe.jsx'

export default function recipes(state = [], action = {}) {
switch(action.type) { 

    case RECIPE_UPDATED:
      return state.map(item => {
          //console.log(item)
          if(item.id === action.recipe.id) return action.recipe;
          return item;
      })

    case RECIPE_FETCH: 
    const index = state.findIndex(item => item.id === action.recipe.id);
    if(index > -1){
        return state.map(item => {
            if(item.id === action.recipe.id) return action.recipe;
            return item;
        });
    }else{
        return [
            ...state,
            action.recipe
        ];
    }

    case SET_RECIPES: return action.recipes;
    default: return state; 
   }
}
```

This is my component file this is where i am having the problem, in my if(id) block the then just underneath the this.props.updatedRecipe.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import classnames from 'classnames';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { Alert } from 'reactstrap';
    import { saveRecipe, fetchRecipe, updateRecipe } from 
     '../../action/index.jsx'
    import styles from './style.js'

  class RecipeForm extends React.Component {
   constructor (props) {
      super(props)
       this.state = {
            id: this.props.recipe ? this.props.recipe.id : null,
            title: this.props.recipe ? this.props.recipe.title : '',
            description: this.props.recipe ? this.props.recipe.description : 
        '',
            imageUrl: this.props.recipe ? this.props.recipe.imageUrl : '',
            errors:{},
            loading: false,
            done: false,
         }
     }

    componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps){
       //console.log(nextProps.recipe)
    this.setState({
        id: nextProps.recipe.id,
        title: nextProps.recipe.title,
        description: nextProps.recipe.description,
        imageUrl: nextProps.recipe.imageUrl,

       })
    }

    componentDidMount ()  {
        if(this.props.match.params.id){
        //console.log(this.props.match.params.id);
        this.props.fetchRecipe(this.props.match.params.id)
      }
  }

   handleChange(event) {
    // this.setState({ [event.target.name] : event.target.value });
    // console.log('updatedRecipe: ' + event.target.id + ' == '+ 
     event.target.value )
    if (!!this.state.errors[event.target.name]){
        let errors = Object.assign({}, this.state.errors);
        delete errors[event.target.name];
        // console.log(errors)
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
             errors
        })
    }else{
        //console.log(this.state)

        this.setState({
               [event.target.name]: event.target.value,

        // let handleChange = Object.assign({}, this.state);
        // handleChange[event.target.id] = event.target.value;
        // this.setState({
        //     recipes: handleChange,
    })    

    }
     }

handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    let errors = {};
    if (this.state.title === '') errors.title = "Can't be empty";
    if (this.state.description === '') errors.description = "Can't be 
      empty";
    if (this.state.imageUrl === '') errors.imageUrl = "Can't be empty";

    this.setState({ 
        errors 
    })
    const isValid = Object.keys(errors).length === 0

    if(isValid){
        const { id, title, description, imageUrl } = this.state;
        //console.log(this.state)
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        if(id){

            this.props.updateRecipe({ id, title, description, imageUrl })
             // this is where the BUG is COMING FROM
            .then(
                ()=>{
                    console.log("see me")
                    this.setState({ done : true, loading: true})},
                (err) => {
                err.response.json()
                .then(({errors}) => {
                    console.log(errors)
                    this.setState({
                    errors})
                }
                )
            }
            )
        }else{
            this.props.saveRecipe({ title, description, imageUrl, })
        .then(
            ()=>{
                this.setState({ done : true, loading: true})},
            (err) => {
            err.response.json()
            .then(({errors}) => {
                console.log(errors)
                this.setState({
                errors})
            }
            )
        }
        )
        }

    }


}

 render() {
    const form = (

        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center 
      container">
        <form className={classnames({ loading: this.state.loading })}>
        <h1 style={styles.header}>Add New Recipe</h1>


        {!!this.state.errors.form && <Alert color="danger"> 
     {this.state.errors.form }</Alert>}
          <div className="form-group row">
            <div className="form-group col-md-12 col-md-offset-8 text- 
      right">
            <div className={classnames('field', { error: 
       !!this.state.errors.title})}>
                <label htmlFor="title">Recipe Title</label>
                <input 
                name="title" 
                value={this.state.title} 
                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                className="form-control" 
                id="title" 
                placeholder="title"/>
                <span style={{color: "#ae5856"}} >{this.state.errors.title} 
     </span>
            </div>
            <div className={classnames('field', { error: 
      !!this.state.errors.description})}>

                <label htmlFor="title">Recipe Description</label>
                <input 
                name="description" 
                value={this.state.description} 
                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                className="form-control" 
                id="description" 
                placeholder="description"/>
               <span style={{color: "#ae5856"}}> 
      {this.state.errors.description}</span>
            </div>
            <div className={classnames('field', { error: 
           !!this.state.errors.imageUrl})}>

                <label htmlFor="imageUrl">Recipe Image</label>
                <input 
                name="imageUrl" 
                value={this.state.imageUrl}
                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}  
                className="form-control" 
                id="imageUrl" 
                placeholder="Image"/>
               <span style={{color: "#ae5856"}}>{this.state.errors.imageUrl} 
          </span>
            </div>
            <div>
                {this.state.imageUrl !== '' && <img src= 
         {this.state.imageUrl} alt="" className="img-rounded"/>}
            </div>
            <button onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} type="submit" 
   className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
            </div>
      </form>
      </div>
    );


    return (

       <div>
           {this.state.done ? <Redirect to="/recipes"/> : form} 
       </div>


       )
    }
 }
 RecipeForm.propTypes = {
    saveRecipe: PropTypes.func.isRequired,

 }

function mapStateToProps(state, props){
   //console.log(props.match.recipe)
   if(props.match.params.id){
   //console.log(props.match.params.id)
   let recipe = {}
   const recipes = state.recipes.filter(item => {
    //console.log(item)
    //console.log(state.recipes)
    if (item.id == props.match.params.id){
        recipe = item
    }
   })
        //console.log(recipe)
    return {
        recipe
    }  

    //console.log(recipe);
  }
   return { recipe: null };
 }

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, { saveRecipe, fetchRecipe }) 
 (RecipeForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should just be `updateRecipe`, not `this.props.updateRecipe`. You're importing `updateRecipe()` (as a function) at the top of the `<RecipeForm/>` component. So it's not a property that's being passed to the component, it's just a function you've imported in that file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! i did what you said. But i got a new error. `   
     Uncaught TypeError: this.updateRecipe is not a function `.. Quick Question the function i am suppose to call there is it the function from my updateRecipe Action? because that is what i am doing...

Comment: Woops sorry, it should just be `updateRecipe`, not `this.updateRecipe` haha. Since the `updateRecipe` function is not associated with the component, it's just an imported function. I'll update my answer

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you should be calling, It's hard for me to say because I don't know exactly what you're trying to do and there's a lot of code in your question. Your `<RecipeForm/>` component doesn't even have a render so I'm not sure what your overall goal is, but Stack Overflow usually deals more with specific issues. If you have general questions about how to structure React/Redux code and components, then documentation and examples will be your best bet, and if you have specific issues/errors then you can post them here :)

Comment: Just did that now but it generated a new kind of error... Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _updateRecipe.updateRecipe)(...).then is not a function.

Comment: I believe it may be the way you export your action dispatcher `updateRecipe()`. While within that function it has access to `.then()` I'm not sure you can append `.then()` to it when calling it elsewhere. Though I admit I'm not too sure as to the cause behind that error and I don't quite understand your overall React/Redux setup here (maybe because it's not optimal, or maybe because of my lack of knowledge). Someone else with better knowledge of Redux and asynchronous code may hopefully be able to help you out with this. Sorry!  :(  I'll keep an eye on this post and help if I can

Comment: Also, as a small point, your file `updateRecipe.jsx` isn't JSX, it's just plain Javascript. So it should just be `updateRecipe.js`. JSX is a HTML/JS blend specific to React, whereas actions and reducers in Redux are just plain Javascript